# Background-image repeats vertically even with no-repeat

Tags: html, css

I have following sets of css:

```
.spinner {
  background-image: url('../assets/spinner.svg');
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 45%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.3;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
}
```

and following html code:

```
<router-outlet>
    <div *ngIf="fetchingData" class="overlay">
        <div class="spinner"></div>
      </div>
</router-outlet>
```

There shouldn't be any way the image should appear twice, but in few devices the image is appearing twice vertically. I increased `.spinner` height to `100%` and image appears thrice vertically along the page.

Setting `background-repeat-y: no-repeat;` has no effect either. If I reduce the height for `.spinner` to say `100px`, I get just one image, but I doubt that might also break in few devices.

Any ideas why the image shows twice.

Comment: Have you checked the image itself? Isn't there the doubling?

Comment: Why don't you use an `img` tag for your svg ?

Comment: no..not at all. The image is a `.gif` file. And the repetition is not just next to each other rather the whole div seems to repeat containing any height given to it

Comment: have you defined `pattern` within your `.svg`? That is where your repeat can come

Comment: can you add some links to images with developer mode opened ?

Comment: @Morpheus: not aware of what you are suggesting

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ replacing `div` with an `img` tag seems to solve it. However I now get a white border (without any other changes) and it won't go even with border : none

Comment: BTW are you sure you can add content inside router-outlet ?
I've build tons of Angular application, never seen anyone to use it like that

Comment: @ShadowFoOrm: It has been in my app for long, only that I was reported this issue on few devices today